# do not read subfolder htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Trying to improve my website performance, i'm thinking to desactivate .htaccess on some part of my website

As i got a structure as 
/img/p/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/

But before to add in Vhost allowOverride, i would to try it, from htaccess, to check performance improvement without any bad side effect

Can we add an allowOverride instruction in .htaccess?

```
<Directory /img/p/>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Everytime i tried i got an 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes from what I know you can have directory tag inside [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory).

```
<Directory "/img/p/">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but even with quotes, as soon as i add <Directory… i got a 500 error

Comment: is there any other rule written apart from this.